# Cannot Retrieve Properties of Node after adding Additional Specificity to Query

Tags: cypher

I'm very new to cypher and just trying to launch some simple queries to get myself situated. Right away, I came across a case which seems strange to me.

Note that nodes labeled as `person` each have property: `dateOfBirth`

Start by asking for all nodes labeled as `person` that are identified by a node labeled as `Identifier` which is in turn an instance of a node labeled as an `IdentifierClass`.

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:is_identified_by]->
(id:Identifier)-[:is_instance_of]->(idClass:IdentifierClass)
 RETURN p
```

Results in, as expected:

```
p
{
  "dateOfBirth": "11/13/2008"
}
{
  "dateOfBirth": "11/13/2008"
}
{
  "dateOfBirth": "11/13/2008"
}
```

Now this is the query I really want to run. We're now specifying that the `IdentifierClass` must have a property `name` with value `id_type_1`.

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:is_identified_by]->
(id:Identifier)-[:is_instance_of]->(idClass:IdentifierClass{name:'id_type_1'})
 RETURN p
```

Results in:

```
p
{

}
{

}
{

}
```

So the same number of results were returned, but now the properties of `p` are not accessible. Why would adding this extra specificity result in a change in variable `p` "upstream"?

Comment: can you return p.dateOfBirth ?

Comment: No, I cannot return p.dateOfBirth in the second scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. The query was working well and in fact there was unexpected data in the graph which led to these results. Several "person" nodes were missing properties.